# how to create a index for json column SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2016 and I am trying to create a index for a json column in a view.

The view itself is built on the json as follows

```
SELECT        
    _id, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.direction') AS direction, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.entryprice') AS entryprice, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exitprice') AS exitprice, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.potentialtarget') AS potentialtarget, 
    FORMAT(CAST(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.entrytime') AS datetimeoffset), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS entrytime, 
    FORMAT(CAST(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exittime') AS datetimeoffset), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS exittime, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.maxfavourable') AS maxfavourable, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.maxagainst') AS maxagainst, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.signal') AS signal, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.instrument') AS instrument, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.account') AS account, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.quantity') AS quantity, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.gains') AS gains, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.hitedge') AS hitedge, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.RealizedProfitLoss') AS RealizedProfitLoss, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.CashValue') AS CashValue, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.BuyingPower') AS BuyingPower, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.maxagainst1ATR') AS maxagainst1ATR, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.maxagainst2ATR') AS maxagainst2ATR, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.Powerbars') AS powerbars, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime[0]') AS PowerbarsTime1, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime[1]') AS PowerbarsTime2, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime[2]') AS PowerbarsTime3, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime[3]') AS PowerbarsTime4, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.PowerbarsTime[4]') AS PowerbarsTime5, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.Powerbarsdetails') AS Powerbarsdetails, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.entrysignal') AS entrysignal, 
    JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exitsignal') AS exitsignal
FROM            
    dbo.Trades
```

I am trying to build a index on _id and some of the datetime columns. I get a error :

> Create failed for Index 'NonClusteredIndex-20161124-152652'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot create index on view 'dbo.vTrades'. It does not have a unique clustered index. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1940)

[image]

Comment: You need to create a unique clustered index on that table, before being able to create your nonclustered index. It says so in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a unique clustered index on your table / view.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cu_indx_ID ON vTrades (id);
```

Then you should be able to create the nonclustered index you want.

**Update:**

Be sure to take a look at the comments on my answer to be aware of valuable additional details.

Comment: **WARNING:** creating a clustered index on a **view** is (1) limited by a large number of preconditions that have to be met, and (2) will "materialize" the view, e.g. physically and persistently store the rows the view shows on disk (other than a "normal" view which doesn't do that), so you might be significantly increasing the size of your database! Just be aware of that !

Comment: `format` and `cast` is non deterministic so you can not create an indexed view unless you remove the `format` and use `convert` with a `style` instead of `cast`.